# Instanceof equivalent in template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, instanceof

I have template class

```
template <typename T>
class BST {
public:
      Node<T>* root;
...
```

and I would like to modify behaviour of insert function depending on T type.

I look for something like

```
if(T instanceof Pair){

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::is_same`:

```
if (std::is_same<T, Pair>::value)
```

Comment: Be aware that is_same will also check the const-ness of the parameter also.

Comment: @user1825608: Depends on what "right" means for you. Is `const int` the same type as `int` to you? Otherwise, `is_same<remove_const<T>::type, Pair>::value`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a specialization of `BST` that takes a `Pair` type and create the `insert` function accordingly:

```
template <>
class BST<Pair>
{
   public:
       insert() { ... }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use "typeid" function in typeinfo header to achieve this in C++.

```
template<class T>
T fun(T a)
{
  if(typeid(T) == typeid(int))
  {
    //Do something
  }
  else if(typeid(T) == typeid(float))
  {
    //Do Something else
  }
}
```